# Serving multiple repos with hg serve. How?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, installation, config

The [wiki](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/hgserve) mentions it's possible to do this under hg serve, but there aren't any examples (such as a sample webdir-conf file). Yes I know it would be better to do this all under Apache, but this is a local machine and hg serve just makes sense for us.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As you've hinted at you use the `hg serve --webdir-conf FILE` invocation and the webdir.conf format is the same as it is for hgweb.cgi.  So those examples apply to you too:

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HgWebDirStepByStep#Preparing_the_config

so at your most basic you can do:

```
[paths]
/repos = /webdata/hg_repos/*
```

where `repos/` is the path on your local system to the directory containing the repositories.

(and you're right it would be much better to take the time to do this under Apache).

Comment: Ok, awesome. So, once I set up collections what URL will I use for cloning? Something like http://10.10.1.252:8000/name_of_repo?

Comment: Yeah, just got to http://10.10.1.252:8000 and you'll see a list of repos whose likes are valid clone sources.

Comment: [paths] should be preferred over [collections]. From your link: "The advised way of specifying collection is now the [paths] section. This has been introduced in Mercurial 1.1"

Comment: I recall liking paths more than collections when it came out in the aughts, but I can't remember why.  I'll update.

Answer (score 8):

use this in your webdir config (for example)

```
foo.config << EOL

[paths]
power = power/Repo
billable = /path/to/billable/Repo
EOL
```

`hg serve --webdir-conf foo.config`

Assuming your repos live in different places...

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative You can use RhodeCode, it's standalone app written in pylons.

"RhodeCode is Pylons framework based Mercurial repository browser/management with build in push/pull server and full text search and permissions system."

A demo can be viewed here.

http://demo.rhodecode.org

Regards

Comment: It appears that link is broken. A demo from the RhodeCode site can be found: http://demo.rhodecode.org/

Comment: All the links are now dead. The website now appears to be https://rhodecode.com/